# How to loop in into multiple elements using single useRef?

Tags: reactjs

I have two inputfield that using a single useRef, I want to get the current.getAttribute to change from password type to text type. But according to docs, only the last element will be selected. I want to use .map to loop into the elements. I can't use the .map to create the elements because every one of them needs to be unique because of my authentication.

Code

```
const passwordRef = useRef();
const handleShowPassword = (e) => {
    console.log(passwordRef.map((e) => console.log(e))); <--- this coz error of passwordRef.map is not a function
    setShowEye(!showEye);
    const type =
      passwordRef.current.getAttribute('type') === 'password'
        ? 'text'
        : 'password';
    passwordRef.current.setAttribute('type', type);
  };

<div className='form-group w-full relative'>
            <PasswordStrength
              type='password'
              placeholder='Current password'
              name='currentPassword'
              ref={passwordRef}
              border={error && error.currentPasswordError ? 'failed' : 'transparent'}
              value={userInfo.currentPassword}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
            {!showEye && (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faEye}
                className='fill-current text-customRed absolute top-4 right-4'
                onClick={handleShowPassword}
              />
            )}
            <label for='password'>
              {showEye && (
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faEyeSlash}
                  className='fill-current text-customRed absolute top-4 right-4'
                  onClick={handleShowPassword}
                />
              )}
              {error && error.passwordError ? (
                <Notifications type='text-failed' field='password'>
                  <span className='text-xxs absolute -left-0 -bottom--7px fadeIn'>
                    {error.msg}
                  </span>
                </Notifications>
              ) : (
                ''
              )}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className='form-group w-full relative'>
            <PasswordStrength
              type='password'
              placeholder='New password'
              name='password'
              ref={passwordRef}
              border={error && error.passwordError ? 'failed' : 'transparent'}
              value={userInfo.password}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
            <label for='password'>
              {error && error.passwordError ? (
                <Notifications type='text-failed' field='password'>
                  <span className='text-xxs absolute -left-0 -bottom--7px fadeIn'>
                    {error.msg}
                  </span>
                </Notifications>
              ) : (
                ''
              )}
            </label>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Even if this would be possible your inputs have hardcoded `type="password"`, so password visibility will be reset on every rerender. But actually you even don't need refs.

Your password fields are almost identical (at least visually). So you could extract the password field into separate component and reuse it twice. The benefit of such recomposition is that you can create inner state indicating if entered password is displayed as text or is hidden.

```
const PasswordField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
  
  return (
    <label>
      {label}:{' '}
      <input
        type={visible ? 'text' : 'password'}
        {...props}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>
        {visible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
      </button>
    </label>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <PasswordField label="Old Password" defaultValue="12345" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <PasswordField label="New Password" defaultValue="12345" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My snippet is intentionally simplified to demonstrate recomposition I mentioned above.

```js
const PasswordField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
  
  return (
    <label>
      {label}:{' '}
      <input
        type={visible ? 'text' : 'password'}
        {...props}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>
        {visible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
      </button>
    </label>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <PasswordField label="Old Password" defaultValue="12345" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <PasswordField label="New Password" defaultValue="12345" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```